# xlsxwriter installed but "No module named xlsxwriter" in psychopy error

Tags: python, module, installation, xlsxwriter, psychopy

I've tried installing xlsxwriter on MacOS

I tried:

```
pip install xlsxwriter
easy_install xlsxwriter
python -m easy_install xlsxwriter
python -m pip install xlsxwriter
```

with

```
pip uninstall xlsxwriter
```

in between each attempt.

I've tried all different versions of Python and Psychopy, and for the life of me, I can't get rid of this error when I try to run Psychopy:

```
"No module named xlsxwriter"
```

I know it's installed because I can search for it (it says it's located in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/XlsxWriter-1.0.0-py2.7.egg)
```

I've tried moving it and copying it to all different levels of my Python folder in "Applications" as well as putting it in the same folder as my .py file I'm trying to run in Psychopy, and I just can't get it to work.

I've tried updating xlsxwriter (it's currently 1.0).

I've tried case-sensitive (XlsxWriter vs. xlswriter).

I've read the forums on this but none of the suggestions have helped so far. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Which version of PsychoPy are you using, and how did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

This actually worked great for me:

1. Make sure/or change directory of your windows python 27 or python 33 is C:\Python27
2. Download XlsxWriter package ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter )
3. Extrat tar file (lookup for tar extractor tool for windows)
4. Open cmd
5. Go to your downlaoded and extracted package directory
6. Type in command prompt: python setup.py install

You can now check module intalled in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

did you tried pip3 install xlsxwriter. worked for me.